# Question on 'especially'

Tags: adverbs

See below a sentence containing an adverbial phrase headed by 'especially'.

> It was very difficult for boats, especially large boats, to cross the river.

I am aware that the adjunct containing 'especially' is supplementary, as indicated by the commas surrounding it. Its meaning, too, I can understand: 'especially' emphasises that it was more difficult for large boats to cross the river than it was for any other kind of boat.

What I do not understand, however, is what 'especially' modifies. Is it the NP in 'large boats' that it modifies, or some other element? Thanks.

Comment: _Especially_ modifies the same thing as _very_, namely the predicate adjective _difficult_. The full sentence would be something like _It was very difficult for boats to cross the river, and it was especially difficult for large boats to cross the river._ Many repeated words have been deleted, including the conjunction, making the interpolation into an apposition.

Answer (score 3):

John Lawler in a comment wrote:

> *Especially* modifies the same thing as *very*, namely the predicate adjective *difficult*. The full sentence would be something like *It was very difficult for boats to cross the river, and it was especially difficult for large boats to cross the river.* Many repeated words have been deleted, including the conjunction, making the interpolation into an apposition.

Answer (score 0):

It modifies the verb "was". Such limited scope of adverbs / adverbials is common in coordinated phrases (e.g.: "I saw a sparrow **this morning** and a robin **yesterday**") and with appositives (e.g.: "I like Marvel characters--**particularly** Spiderman--who have super senses"). This issue is dealt with in Quirk et al. (CGEL) section 13.54: "Coordination and the scope of adverbials". I would consider your example sentence to contain an appositive.

Note that other people will use different terminology. This is just one interpretation; others are certainly possible.

Comment: Notice that Quirk et al don't see the copula as being modified by the adverb, but the whole matrix independent clause. << _Yesterday_ the sun was very warm >> <<  A [S Vcop C] >>. But I go with the appositive / parallel analysis: 'It was very difficult for boats ... in particular it was very difficult for large boats ...'. 'Especially' attaches to '[It was very difficult for] large boats'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth CGEL also gives examples in which the adverbials modify constituents smaller than clauses in the next section (13.55). I don't think that they are necessarily required to modify entire clauses. I think that there are multiple ways to parse this sentence and that the practical difference is pretty minor.

Comment: It's the suggested modification of 'be' by an adverb / adverbial that's dubious. [Yesterday] [the sun was very warm] not [Very warm, the sun] {[was] [yesterday]}.

Answer (score 0):

> It was very difficult for boats, especially large boats, to cross the river.

There should be another comma after "especially": It was very difficult for boats, especially**,** large boats, to cross the river.

*(If there is no comma, then it refers to "{especially large boats}. i.e. boats that were exceptionally huge.)*

With this amendment, we have

It was very difficult for boats, especially **for** large boats, to cross the river.

= It was very difficult for boats to cross the river. Especially, it was very difficult **for** large boats to cross the river .

Especially is a free modifier and adverbially modifies the whole of the clause "it was very difficult **for** large boats to cross the river."

Answer (score 0):

Google's definition drawn from on Oxford Languages of **especially**:

> 1. used to single out one person, thing, or situation over all others.
>    "he despised them all, especially Sylvester"
> 2. to a great extent; very much.

There are at least two possibilities here, depending on whether or not "... 'especially' emphasises that it was more difficult for large boats to cross the river than it was for any other kind of boat" is what is meant.

If that is what is meant, then *especially* is replacing *very*, and it carries a higher level of difficulty than *very*. It was very difficult for boats to cross the river, and it was especially difficult for large boats to cross the river. This relies on the second definition.

An alternative use would be to align the rather vague "It was very difficult for boats to cross the river" with a particular, more restrictive context. Perhaps we were only concerned with large boats at the moment. In that case, we aren't saying it is even more difficult for large boats to cross the river, we are providing assurance that it is very difficult for large boats to cross the river. Here, *especially* is taken to modify the entire assertion regarding *large boats*. This relies on the first definition of *especially*.

Free modifiers can be divided into two classes, sentence free modifiers and verb free modifiers. The first case is an example of the verb free modifier and the second case is an example of the sententence free modifier.

> "[Joost] Buysschaert ["Criteria for Classification of English Adverbials," 1982] distinguishes between complements and free modifiers. The distinction is basically a syntactic one. . . . Complements invariably go in end position; hence if an adverbial occurs in front or medial position, it is a free modifier.
> "There are two types of free modifiers. V[erb]-modifying and S[entence]-modifying. The former type adds 'information about the action, process or state described in the relation denoted by the verb. This information is not relevant to the rest of the proposition' (1982: 87). The latter type modifies the entire proposition. Front position is said to be reserved for S-modifiers; thus if an adverbial can be fronted, it is an S-modifying free modifier. However, according to Buysschaert, some S-modifiers are locked in medial position and cannot be fronted, e.g. just, ever, still. In such cases the distinguishing criterion is not mobility, but the semantic scope of the adverbial, i.e. it should modify the whole proposition, not just the relation expressed by the verb."
> (Hilde Hasselgård, Adjunct Adverbials in English. Cambridge University Press, 2010)
>
> https://www.thoughtco.com/free-modifier-grammar-1690807

*Particularly* follows the same pattern of having separate dictionary definitions for the verbal and sentential modifier uses.